# django template doesn't load image uploaded in ImageField properly

Tags: python, django, django-media

i know this question have been brought up a lot of times,but i have tried a lot of different things,not working add.i belive i might have forget to add something silly in my code,just cant figure out what.below is the code of my heading model:

```
class Heading(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=5000)
    content = RichTextField()
    image= models.ImageField(null=True,blank=True)
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.now())
    time = models.TimeField(default=datetime.now())
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, null=True, blank=True)
```

i have also added below codes in my projects settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

below is my urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url ,patterns
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),
    url(r'^ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
    url(r'^grappelli/', include('grappelli.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^news/', include('news.urls')),
]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns(
        'django.views.static',
        (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)',
        'serve',
        {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}), )
```

this is how my directory is set up 
[image: directory]

below is my template code

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

        {%block main_meat%}
        {%if headings%}
                {%for heading in headings%}
                    <h1><a href="/news/headline/{{heading.slug}}">{{heading.title}}</a></h1>
                    <br>
                    <img src='{{heading.image}}'>
                    {{heading.content|safe}}
                {%endfor%}

        {%endif%}
    {%endblock%}
```

when i inspect element on a webbrowser,this is the path of image that i get

```
<img src="./image_name.png">
```

subash is the name of my project and news is the name of the app.i know i have posted a long question with lots of codes,please if anyone can point out what i am missing.

Comment: Do you have the MEDIA_ROOT configured in your settings.py?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your template intead of:

```
<img src='{{heading.image}}'>
```

try:

```
{% if heading.image %}
    <img src='{{heading.image.url}}'>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: it works when i do that,but only if i upload image on every heading object that i create,else i get this error:The 'image' attribute has no file associated with it. and there might be case when i don't have images for every heading object,what might be the fix?